# Show DialogBox in loop in android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to show dialog boxes with contents from the database .The fetched data from the database may contain more than 1 data.So I have to show dialog in for loop.But the dialog shows only for the first row in the database.Here is the code

```
cursor = sqldb.query(Database_Handler.dbdectab, null,"((" + Database_Handler.gendtime + "<='" + after_1hr + "' and " + Database_Handler.gendtime + ">='" + before_1hr + "') and (" 
            + Database_Handler.calused + "='Gregorian' or " + Database_Handler.calused + "='both')) ", null, null, null, null);
    notif_count = cursor.getCount();
    //dec_name_ctr_builder = new StringBuilder("");
    if(notif_count>0)
    {
        dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            dec_name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_Handler.decname));

            dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_alert);

            TextView tv_alert = (TextView)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.txt_alert);
            tv_alert.setText( dec_name );
            Button yes = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
            Button no = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);

            yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(donateurl));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                    cursor.close();
                    sqldb.close();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                    cursor.close();
                    sqldb.close();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            dialog1.show();
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and checked that how many times the control is coming inside the do wile loop

Comment: Yes...it comes 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Android dialog boxes are not modal (which is to say, they don't block the background processes).Hence your work is done asycnhronuosly and according to :

**Romain guy**

```
We've designed Android to prevent developers from writing synchronous dialogs so you don't really have much of a choice.
```

SO you can not block the while loop execution in between using Dialog.

Comment: Actually,i dont need to block the while loop execution.I only want to show the dialog box one after the other when user click any button on the dialog.

Comment: Using the basic dialog building blocks it is not possible to have them stack, you will need to re-show the first dialog. The reason for this is that when you press a dialog button it internally will dismiss the dialog as part of the process for calling the click handler you assigned for each button in the dialog builder API.

Answer (score 0):

Karan_Rana  is right. The simplest solution for your answer would be storing the results somewhere else and displaying a new dialog each time some data is left and user clicks on a previous dialogs button.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I had a similar problem once. I used recursion to loop a dialog box. My situation was unique as I needed to detect an internet connection during app startup. So, this approach may not work for you. But I was able to implement the solution without for loops and blocking the main UI thread. Because I was on a splash screen, there was no other UI I needed to contend so I would simple call the dialog box again until the user chooses to "Quit".

I had a splash screen that would only continue to the landing activity of the app if a network connection was detected.

Sample code below to demonstrate the concept. Note that there are custom methods, but you should get the idea to call the prompt again from within onClick method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
       launchApp();
    } else {
        retryPrompt();
    }

}

private void retryPrompt() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            launchApp();
        } else {
            final ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog.CustomAlertBuilder(this,
                    "Internet Connection",
                    "Internet Connection not detected. Please check your connection.",
                    "Retry").
                    setNegBtnLabel("Quit").
                    setCustomCallback(new CustomDialogCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClickPositiveBtn(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            // go around again.
                            retryPrompt(); // <<== Call method recursively
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onClickNegativeBtn(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            // abort app.
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).build();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```